# Show only specific flipchart-Widget

Tags: flutter

I have to make a simple study app for a school project, where I want that the user can repeat only the question, which he marked as wrong. Those should be shown as the "original" flipchart. In the class Auswertung I created a button which should have this task. In my Code you just chose one or multiple themes with mulitiple questions each. Than the Flipcharts are shown like they should be. After a specific amount of asnwered questions (currently 2) you get navigated to the overview page, where it should be possible to repeat only the Flipcharts which where marked as wrong.

The following class is for choosing the themes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import '../../widgets/Baden-Württemberg/Fragen/FlipchartsBW.item.dart';

class FragenBW extends StatefulWidget {
  const FragenBW({super.key, required wrongQuestions});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _FragenBWState createState() => _FragenBWState();
}

class _FragenBWState extends State<FragenBW> {
  String number = '';
  final List<String> _themes = [
    'Theme 1',
    'Theme 2',
    'Theme 3',
    'Theme 4',
    'Theme 5',
    'Theme 6',
    'Theme 7',
    'Theme 8',
  ];

  final List<bool> _selected = List.filled(8, false);

  final Map<String, List<Flipchart>> _flipcharts = {
    'Theme 1': [
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 1', answer: 'Answer 1'),
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 1.1', answer: 'Answer 1.2'),
    ],
    'Theme 2': [
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 2', answer: 'Answer 2'),
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 2.2', answer: 'Answer 2.2'),
    ],
    'Theme 3': [
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 3', answer: 'Answer 3'),
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 3.2', answer: 'Answer 3.2'),
    ],
    'Theme 4': [
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 4', answer: 'Answer 4'),
      Flipchart(question: '4.2', answer: 'Answer 4.2'),
    ],
    'Theme 5': [
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 5', answer: 'Answer 5'),
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 5.2', answer: 'Answer 5.2'),
    ],
    'Theme 6': [
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 6', answer: 'Answer 6'),
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 6.2', answer: 'Answer 6.2'),
    ],
    'Theme 7': [
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 7', answer: 'Answer  7'),
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 7.2', answer: 'Answer 7.2'),
    ],
    'Theme 8': [
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 8', answer: 'Answer 8'),
      Flipchart(question: 'Question 8.2', answer: 'Answer 8.2'),
    ],
    // Add more flipcharts for each theme
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
          title: const CustomAppBar(title: "Questions/Answers"),
          bottom: const PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(10),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            for (int i = 0; i < _themes.length; i++)
              CheckboxListTile(
                value: _selected[i],
                onChanged: (bool? value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selected[i] = value ?? false;
                  });
                },
                title: Text(
                  _themes[i],
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                      width: 1.0,
                      color: Colors.grey[850]!,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid)),
              child: TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    'learning',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    bool atLeastOneSelected = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < _selected.length; i++) {
                      if (_selected[i]) {
                        atLeastOneSelected = true;
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                    if (atLeastOneSelected) {
                      // Code to navigate to next screen
                      List<Flipchart> selectedFlipcharts = [];
                      for (int i = 0; i < _themes.length; i++) {
                        if (_selected[i]) {
                          selectedFlipcharts.addAll(_flipcharts[_themes[i]]!);
                        }
                      }

                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => FlipchartBW(
                              flipcharts: selectedFlipcharts.toList()),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class Flipchart {
  final String question;
  final String answer;

  Flipchart({required this.question, required this.answer});

  String get getName => question;
  String get getContent => answer;
}






class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const CustomAppBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[850],
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 76,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // IconButton(
                //   icon: const Icon(
                //    Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                //    color: Colors.white,
                //    size: 25,
                //   ),
                //     onPressed: () {
                //        Navigator.pop(context);
                //     },
                //       ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The next Class is for the flipcharts:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jagd/widgets/Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg/Fragen/Auswertung.item.dart';
import 'package:jagd/widgets/CustomAppBar.item.dart';

import '../../../Pages/Baden-Württemberg/FragenBW.item.dart';

class FlipchartBW extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Flipchart> flipcharts;

  const FlipchartBW({Key? key, required this.flipcharts}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _FlipchartBWState createState() => _FlipchartBWState();
}

class _FlipchartBWState extends State<FlipchartBW>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  bool showAnswer = false;
  int correct = 0;
  int wrong = 0;
  List<Flipchart> wrongQuestions = [];

  void rightButtonPressed() {
    correct++;
    checkAnswers();
  }

  void wrongButtonPressed() {
    wrong++;
    wrongQuestions.add(widget.flipcharts[currentIndex]);
    checkAnswers();
  }

  void checkAnswers() {
    if (correct + wrong == 1) {
      // Change Number of Queastions that have to be answered
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Auswertung(
                    correct: correct,
                    wrong: wrong,
                    wrongQuestions: wrongQuestions,
                    numberofQuestions: 5,
                  )));
    }
  }

  void nextQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % widget.flipcharts.length;
      showAnswer = false;
    });
  }

  void previousQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      if (currentIndex == 0) {
        currentIndex = currentIndex;
      } else {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + widget.flipcharts.length) %
            widget.flipcharts.length;
      }
      showAnswer = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
        title: const CustomAppBar(title: "Questions/Answers"),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(10),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 10,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: wrong,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: correct,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  widget.flipcharts[currentIndex].question,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 0, 50, 0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 1.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[850]!,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                child: Visibility(
                  visible: !showAnswer,
                  child: TextButton(
                    child: const Text(
                      "Show Answer",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        showAnswer = true;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Visibility(
                  visible: showAnswer,
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 200,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        widget.flipcharts[currentIndex].answer,
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 100,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 25),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 1.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[850]!,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: previousQuestion,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.navigate_before, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 4,
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: showAnswer,
                child: Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            width: 1.0,
                            color: Colors.grey[850]!,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: const Text("WRONG",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          wrong++;
                        });
                        checkAnswers();
                        nextQuestion();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 4,
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: showAnswer,
                child: Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            width: 1.0,
                            color: Colors.grey[850]!,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                    child: TextButton(
                      child: const Text("RIGHT",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          correct++;
                        });
                        checkAnswers();
                        nextQuestion();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 4,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 1.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[850]!,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: nextQuestion,
                  child: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const CustomAppBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[850],
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 76,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // IconButton(
                //   icon: const Icon(
                //    Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                //    color: Colors.white,
                //    size: 25,
                //   ),
                //     onPressed: () {
                //        Navigator.pop(context);
                //     },
                //       ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The last part is for the overview and the button for the repeat of the wrong Flipcharts

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jagd/Pages/Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg/FragenBW.item.dart';
import 'package:jagd/widgets/CustomAppBar.item.dart';

class Auswertung extends StatelessWidget {
  const Auswertung(
      {super.key,
      required this.correct,
      required this.wrong,
      required int numberofQuestions,
      required List<Flipchart> wrongQuestions});
  final int correct;
  final int wrong;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
          appBar: // here the desired height
              AppBar(
            title: const CustomAppBar(title: "Overview"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  const Center(
                                    child: Text("Right:",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 15.5)),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text("$correct",
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.green,
                                          fontSize: 40,
                                        )),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  const Center(
                                    child: Text("Wrong:",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 15.5)),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text("$wrong",
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.red, fontSize: 40)),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7)),
                  ),
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text('Repeat Wrong questions',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 15.5)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}



class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const CustomAppBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[850],
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 76,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 0, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                // IconButton(
                //   icon: const Icon(
                //    Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                //    color: Colors.white,
                //    size: 25,
                //   ),
                //     onPressed: () {
                //        Navigator.pop(context);
                //     },
                //       ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to save them in a List named wrongQuestions but that does not ork quiet as I expected. ChatGPT could not help me aswell

Comment: Is `Auswertung` is used on `home`? can you include how you are using this widget. btw it would be better if you could provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No, Auswertung is not used as home. In my app the Quiz is just a part of the whole app. When I open the FragenBW page you can choose the themes with the flipcharts, than you press on learning to show the flipcharts. The form of them are defined in the FlipchartBW page. After 1 question answered you get navigated to the Aswertung screen, where it should be possible to repeat only the flipcharts which where markes as wrong

Comment: try to remove MaterialApp from `Auswertung`, you just need one MaterialApp for the project on general case

Comment: It does nothing. I made a new Question on Stackoverflow an hour ago and im going to delete this one. In the new one i managed to show the green and blue container from the wrongFlipcards, but not the text.